# iOS VOIP push disturbed VOIP service

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit, pushkit

We have been facing issue in our VOIP communication app for a long time. Our  application uses Pushkit and call kit for VOIP calls. Normally everything works fine like we receive proper VOIP push and calls happening properly. But sometimes calling doesn't work and device goes to sort of deadlock. At that time none of the VOIP app works including WhatsApp. So we have to restart device to let VOIP service work properly.

Now we wanna know what could be the reason for such situation, when our app blocks whole device VOIP services including itself.

Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: I have worked on VOIP apps, but such situation never happened. It can be exactly get once i can check your code.

Comment: Worked on Callkit app never have this, IMHO it's better if you ask on http://forums.developer.apple.com/